# what are the so-called dirty states of a checkbox in the DataGridView checkbox column?

Tags: c#, winforms

When I use the event `CurrentCellDirtyStateChange()` I started to wonder: What are the dirty states of a CheckBox in DataGridViewCheckBox?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> A cell is marked as modified if its contents have changed but the
>   change has not been saved.
>
> This event typically occurs when a cell has been edited but the change
>   has not been committed to the data cache, or when an edit operation is
>   canceled.

[MSDN Documentation of currentcelldirtystatechanged](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview.currentcelldirtystatechanged%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

when it changes !
i think this an option to collect the data and/or the behavior of the user to that particular field in that particular form.